# Elixir: best practice to extract data from nested structs

Tags: elixir

In Elixir we can get data from nested data structures using

```
data = %{field: %{other_field: 1}}
data[:field][:other_field]
```

If it contains lists it also can be done using

```
data = %{field: %{other_field: [1]}}
get_in data, [:field, :other_field, Access.at(0)]
```

But how to get that data given that data.field.other_field is a structure?
Both of the above would fail because structs don't implement `Access.fetch/2`.

```
data = %{field: %{other_field: %Struct{a: 1}}}
```

So what's the right way to access nested structs data other than pattern matching?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.7/Access.html#key/2):

> **key(key, default \\ nil)**
>
> Accesses the given key in a map/struct.
>
> Uses the default value if the key does not exist or if the value being accessed is `nil`.

```
iex(1)> defmodule Struct do
...(1)>   defstruct [:a]
...(1)> end
iex(2)> data = %{field: %{other_field: %Struct{a: 1}}}
%{field: %{other_field: %Struct{a: 1}}}
iex(3)> get_in data, [:field, :other_field, Access.key(:a)]
1
iex(4)> get_in data, [:field, :other_field, Access.key(:b, :default)]
:default
```

Answer (score 2):

I use my implementation of ruby's try operator for this.

```
@spec try(Access.t(), nonempty_list(node) | atom, term) :: term
def try(data, keys, default \\ nil)

def try(nil, _keys, default), do: default

def try(data, keys, default) when is_atom(keys) do
  try(data, [keys], default)
end

def try(data, keys, default) when length(keys) == 1 do
  get_in(data, [Access.key(hd(keys), default)])
end

def try(data, keys, default) do
  get_in(data, [Access.key(hd(keys))])
  |> try(tl(keys), default)
end
```

Usage in your example

```
try(data, [:field, :other_field, :a]) # with default nil

try(data, [:field, :other_field, :a], 42) # with default 42

try(data, :single_field_as_atom) # with a single value
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic implementation is provided in the [`Accessible`](https://hexdocs.pm/accessible/) and [`StructAccess`](https://hexdocs.pm/struct_access) libraries.

This allows you to use the familiar `Map` syntax.

```
data = %Data{field: %{other_field: 1}}
data[:field][:other_field]
```